# Convert Column to Date Format (Pandas Dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows:

```
Symbol  Date
A       02/20/2015
A       01/15/2016
A       08/21/2015
```

I want to sort it by `Date`, but the column is just an `object`.

I tried to make the column a date object, but I ran into an issue where that format is not the format needed. The format needed is `2015-02-20,` etc.

So now I'm trying to figure out how to have numpy convert the 'American' dates into the ISO standard, so that I can make them date objects, so that I can sort by them.

How would I convert these american dates into ISO standard, or is there a more straight forward method I'm missing within pandas?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_datetime()` to convert to a datetime object. It takes a format parameter, but in your case I don't think you need it.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame( {'Symbol':['A','A','A'] ,
    'Date':['02/20/2015','01/15/2016','08/21/2015']})
>>> df
         Date Symbol
0  02/20/2015      A
1  01/15/2016      A
2  08/21/2015      A
>>> df['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
>>> df.sort('Date') # This now sorts in date order
        Date Symbol
0 2015-02-20      A
2 2015-08-21      A
1 2016-01-15      A
```

For future search, you can change the sort statement:

```
>>> df.sort_values(by='Date') # This now sorts in date order
        Date Symbol
0 2015-02-20      A
2 2015-08-21      A
1 2016-01-15      A
```

Comment: I also have a df['Date'].unique() before the sort, which returns a series instead of a Dataframe. This makes 02/20/2015 into 2015-02-19T18:00:00.000000000-0600 which then gets split into 2015-02-19. Is there a way to add a day? Or a more formal way to correct this?

Comment: `df.Date.astype(np.int64)` should work for epoch time

Comment: Turns out that epoch would be wrong since its assuming times of 18:00 hours etc. I need them to be 00:00 hours. I have a way to convert to epoch if I could just get the date objects to not have a time, or the wrong time.

Comment: for me `pd.to_datetime(df.Date)[0]` returns `Timestamp('2015-02-20 00:00:00')`

Comment: Starting new question with more formal description of issue

Comment: It looks like there may actually be [a faster way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31857163/2071807) of converting strings into dates.

Answer (score 151):

`sort` method has been [deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html) and replaced with [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values). After converting to datetime object using `df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])`

```
df.sort_values(by=['Date'])
```

Note: to sort *in-place* and/or in a descending order (the most recent first):

```
df.sort_values(by=['Date'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use it with: 
    df.sort_values(by=['Date'])

Comment: I was wracking my brain wondering why there were duplicates in my sorting. inplace=True fixed that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 11):

[@JAB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161433/2071807) is fast and concise. But it changes the `DataFrame` you are trying to sort, which you may or may not want.

<sub>(**Note**: You almost certainly *will* want it, because your date columns should be dates, not strings!)</sub>

In the unlikely event that you don't want to change the dates into dates, you can also do it a different way.

First, get the index from your sorted `Date` column:

```
In [25]: pd.to_datetime(df.Date).order().index
Out[25]: Int64Index([0, 2, 1], dtype='int64')
```

Then use it to index your original `DataFrame`, leaving it untouched:

```
In [26]: df.ix[pd.to_datetime(df.Date).order().index]
Out[26]: 
        Date Symbol
0 2015-02-20      A
2 2015-08-21      A
1 2016-01-15      A
```

Magic!

**Note:** for Pandas versions 0.20.0 and later, use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) instead of `ix`, which is now deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

Since *`pandas >= 1.0.0`* we have the `key` argument in [**`DataFrame.sort_values`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html). This way we can sort the dataframe by specifying a key and without adjusting the original dataframe:

```
df.sort_values(by="Date", key=pd.to_datetime)
```

```
  Symbol        Date
0      A  02/20/2015
2      A  08/21/2015
1      A  01/15/2016
```

Comment: thanks man, it's precise and quick

Answer (score -1):

The data containing the date column can be read by using the below code:

```
data = pd.csv(file_path,parse_dates=[date_column])
```

Once the data is read by using the above line of code, the column containing the information about the date can be accessed using `pd.date_time()` like:

```
pd.date_time(data[date_column], format = '%d/%m/%y')
```

to change the format of date as  per the requirement.

Answer (score -1):

```
data['Date'] = data['Date'].apply(pd.to_datetime) # non-null datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.