# Plotting in Python with Date time values

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, machine-learning, time-series

I am trying to do time series analysis on my data of website pageviews:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyflux as pf
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

data = pd.read_csv('pageviews.csv')
data = data[:100]
print(data.head())
# data.index = data['timestamp'].values

plt.figure(figsize=(30,15))
plt.plot(data['timestamp'], data['event_count'])
plt.ylabel('Event Counts')
plt.title('Page Views')
```

I am following the tutorial

Amazingly, my plot of time series looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ul9wp.jpg

Here is sample of my data:

```
              timestamp  event_count
0  2017-10-05T18:00:00Z         1691
1  2017-10-05T19:00:00Z         1436
2  2017-08-13T06:00:00Z          735
3  2017-08-13T07:00:00Z          706
4  2017-08-13T05:00:00Z          780
```

What is going wrong I can't understand?

The tutorial is here http://pyflux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arima.html.

Comment: The order in the timestamp column look a bit off, have you tried sorting it?

Comment: @KarlAnka how to sort by timestamp?

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161356/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-date

Comment: @KarlAnka DID data['timestamp'] =pd.to_datetime(data.timestamp)
data.sort('timestamp') not working

Comment: Try:
`data['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data.timestamp)` and then
`data = data.sort_values(by='datetime')`