# How to sort timevalues in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I used following code to get a dataframe groupby table

```
df1=df.groupby(['timestampEpochSecond'],sort=True)['metricValue'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
df_summary=pd.Series.to_frame(df1)

df_summary.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_summary.rename(index=str,columns=    {'timestampEpochSecond':'splunk_query_mins'},inplace=True)
df_summary
```

The table is like

splunk_query_mins

metricValue

0
2018-12-13 06:41 1200.0

1
2018-12-13 06:07 238.0

2
2018-12-13 06:47 42.0

3
2018-12-13 09:54 14.0

4
2018-12-13 16:40 10.0

5
2018-12-12 21:30 5.0

6
2018-12-13 08:12 3.0

7
2018-12-13 01:11 3.0

8
0 0.0

However, when I used

```
df1.sort_values(by=''splunk_query_mins',ascending=True)
```

I got the error TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
Again, thank you so much for helping me

Comment: There is an extra quote in the last code line: `... by=''splunk ...`.

Comment: Should the last line not be `df_summary.sort_values(by='splunk_query_mins', ascending=True)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the column `splunk_query_mins` is of the wrong `dtype` - it is likely a `object`. I think you will first need to convert `splunk_query_mins` to `datetime`. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28161433/4057186), which shows what you might be trying to do.

It probably requires something like this

```
df1['splunk_query_mins'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.splunk_query_mins)
df1.sort_values(by='splunk_query_mins', ascending=True)
```

EDIT: If, for some reason, you want to keep the `splunk_query_mins` column as `object` (instead of changing it to `datetime`), then you have to try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31856487/4057186) - replace `.ix` by `.loc`.