# How to split list items newline in to comma in python

Tags: python-3.x, data-science, strip

I used this

```
print(listing_jobs)
```

resulted in this

```
['Senior Cloud Specialist\nFull-time · Singapore · 5 - 10 Years\n12 days ago', 'Cloud Native Developer\nFull-time · Hyderabad · 2 - 5 Years\n13 days ago']
```

How can I convert `\n` to comma?

When I use

```
listing_jobs.strip().split('\n')
```

it's showing error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question well, you want to split the elements of the list `listing_jobs` by `\n` ? if so, you can use list comprehension as follows:

```
d = ['Senior Cloud Specialist\nFull-time · Singapore · 5 - 10 Years\n12 days ago',
 'Cloud Native Developer\nFull-time · Hyderabad · 2 - 5 Years\n13 days ago']
d = [x.strip().split("\n") for x in d]
```

That will give the following list of lists:

```
[['Senior Cloud Specialist',
  'Full-time . Singapore . 5 - 10 Years',
  '12 days ago'],
 ['Cloud Native Developer',
  'Full-time . Hyderabad . 2 - 5 Years',
  '13 days ago']]
```

But you will end up with a list of lists. If you want to flatten it to a list of strings, do the following:

```
result = []
for el in d:
     result = result + el
```

output:

```
['Senior Cloud Specialist',
 'Full-time . Singapore . 5 - 10 Years',
 '12 days ago',
 'Cloud Native Developer',
 'Full-time . Hyderabad . 2 - 5 Years',
 '13 days ago']
```

---

Overall code:

```
# original data
d = ['Senior Cloud Specialist\nFull-time · Singapore · 5 - 10 Years\n12 days ago',
 'Cloud Native Developer\nFull-time · Hyderabad · 2 - 5 Years\n13 days ago']
# split by "\n"
d = [x.strip().split("\n") for x in d]
# flatten the list of lists into a list of strings
result = []
for el in d:
     result = result + el
```

---

Why you have the following error?

> "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'"

Because strip can be applied on `str` (string) type and you are applying it on a list.

Comment: how i change the order according to the date of posting(Most old first)

Comment: You can apply a lambda to sort like this `sorted(result, key=lambda x: sort_by_date(x))`, before that you need to define a function `sort_by_date` in which you extract the date from string to a number and return it from the function so it used for sorting.

Comment: job_name                               details  \
0                  Sr.QA Engineer   Full-time · Hyderabad · 3 - 5 Years               time  
0    9 hours ago  
  
 
1         Senior Cloud Specialist  Full-time · Singapore · 5 - 10 Years  
1    12 days ago 

2          Cloud Native Developer   Full-time · Hyderabad · 2 - 5 Years   
2    13 days ago 

how i store the data according to the date of posting(Most old first) as a DataFrame in CSV

Comment: if the data is in a list you an do `pd.DataFrame(data)`, it it's a in a csv file, you can do `pd.read_csv("path_to_csv_file", sep=",")`. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks for your help how i sort table data's based on time 9 hours ago,2 months ago in pandas

Comment: Here's an example on how to sort a dataframe based on date: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161356/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-date

Comment: but its date in my table its a string like 9 hours ago and 1 month ago etc..how i can sort based on this     showing error ('Unknown string format:', '9 hours ago')

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your list of strings, and replace `\n` with a `,`

```
listing_jobs = ['Senior Cloud Specialist\nFull-time · Singapore · 5 - 10 Years\n12 days ago', 'Cloud Native Developer\nFull-time · Hyderabad · 2 - 5 Years\n13 days ago']

jobs = [job.replace('\n',',') for job in listing_jobs]
print(jobs)
#['Senior Cloud Specialist,Full-time · Singapore · 5 - 10 Years,12 days ago', #'Cloud Native Developer,Full-time · Hyderabad · 2 - 5 Years,13 days ago']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import  re
list_of_lines = ['Senior Cloud Specialist\nFull-time · Singapore · 5 - 10 Years\n12 days ago', 'Cloud Native Developer\nFull-time · Hyderabad · 2 - 5 Years\n13 days ago']

just_replace = [re.sub('\n',",",lines) for lines in list_of_lines]

replace_then_split_to_list_of_lists = [re.sub('\n',",",lines).split(',') for lines in list_of_lines]

replace_and_then_split_to_flat_list = sum([re.sub('\n',",",lines).split(',') for lines in list_of_lines],[])

no_replace_split_flat_list = sum([lines.split('\n') for lines in list_of_lines],[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

for item in listing_jobs:
    print(item.replace('\n',','))