# Sorting daily data in monthly groups with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a daily streamflow data for 11 years as in the picture. I want to sort the streamflow values in descending order for every month (every month has its own descending order i.e 10th month is going like 107,98,86... and and 11th month is like 170,154,144,... but they are all in same dataframe)

[image: Excel file]

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Better is generate some sample data like `np.random.seed(2020)
rng = pd.date_range('1989-10-01', periods=50)
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE (Month, Day, Year)': rng, 
                   'STREAMFLOW (CFS)': np.random.randint(1000, size=50)})`

Comment: Also what is expected output `DataFrame` ? Can you add first 10 rows of first month data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert column `DATE` to datetimes if necessary by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then create months periods column by [`Series.dt.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) an dlast sorting by multiple columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
np.random.seed(2020)
rng = pd.date_range('1989-10-01', periods=50)
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE (Month, Day, Year)': rng, 
                   'STREAMFLOW (CFS)': np.random.randint(1000, size=50)})  
print (df.head(10))
  DATE (Month, Day, Year)  STREAMFLOW (CFS)
0              1989-10-01               864
1              1989-10-02               392
2              1989-10-03               323
3              1989-10-04               630
4              1989-10-05               707
5              1989-10-06                91
6              1989-10-07               637
7              1989-10-08               643
8              1989-10-09               583
9              1989-10-10               952
```

---

```
#already datetimes
#df['DATE (Month, Day, Year)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE (Month, Day, Year)'], dayfirst=True)

df['per'] = df['DATE (Month, Day, Year)'].dt.to_period('m')

df = df.sort_values(['per', 'STREAMFLOW (CFS)', ], ascending=[True, False])
print (df.head(10))
   DATE (Month, Day, Year)  STREAMFLOW (CFS)      per
29              1989-10-30               980  1989-10
14              1989-10-15               970  1989-10
20              1989-10-21               958  1989-10
9               1989-10-10               952  1989-10
13              1989-10-14               920  1989-10
22              1989-10-23               870  1989-10
0               1989-10-01               864  1989-10
28              1989-10-29               806  1989-10
15              1989-10-16               777  1989-10
4               1989-10-05               707  1989-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert your date columns to a pandas datetime object using

```
df['Date'] =pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Then sort by date

```
df.sort_values(by='Date')
```

You can see a more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161356/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-date)