# How to sort pandas dataframe rows by datetime column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-datetime

With the following code I am expecting the dataframe (rows) to be sorted from *oldest* to *latest* *timestamp*. Something like this...

```
         #raw_dataframe#                         #sorted dataframe#
  Symbol          tagdatetime             Symbol          tagdatetime
0      A  2020-03-01 01:00:00           0      B  2020-01-01 01:00:00
1      B  2020-01-01 01:00:00   ===>    1      A  2020-03-01 01:00:00
2      C  2020-06-01 01:00:00           2      C  2020-06-01 01:00:00
```

But the actual output is unsorted for the following code,

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Symbol':['A','B','C'] ,
    'tagdatetime':['2020-03-01 01:00:00','2020-01-01 01:00:00','2020-06-01 01:00:00']})
print(df,"\n-------------------------------")
df['tagdatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tagdatetime'], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").sort_values()
print(df)

Output:
      Symbol          tagdatetime
    0      A  2020-03-01 01:00:00
    1      B  2020-01-01 01:00:00
    2      C  2020-06-01 01:00:00 
    -------------------------------
     Symbol         tagdatetime
    0      A 2020-03-01 01:00:00
    1      B 2020-01-01 01:00:00
    2      C 2020-06-01 01:00:00
```

And I have tried many other [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161356/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-date), but none seems working for me.
where am I doing wrong?
what happens to sort when I have two or more rows with the same timestamp?

Please answer..

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Symbol':['A','B','C'] ,
    'tagdatetime':['2020-03-01 01:00:00','2020-01-01 01:00:00','2020-06-01 01:00:00']})

df['tagdatetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tagdatetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.sort_values(by='tagdatetime', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

You need to convert column `tagdatetime` to datetime format before sorting & then sort values by column `tagdatetime`

Comment: datetime is correctly parsed by the OP - the point is to update the `df`, either with `inplace=True` or `df = df.sort_values(by='tagdatetime')`

Comment: Answer that I've posted is a generalized so it could carter larger audience. The OP clearly mentions that he is unable to sort I've answered that in my post. OP did parsed correctly.