# Why is my matplotlib timeseries graph is in such a mess?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts, time-series

I've tried to come out with the historical chart using matplotlib, but the chart doesn't show the correct format.

```
plt.rc('figure', figsize=(15, 10))
  fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, 
              gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [3, 1]})
  fig.tight_layout(pad=3)

  date = data['Date']
  close = data['MClose']
  vol = data['MVolume']

  plot_price = axes[0]
  plot_price.plot(date, close, color=colors['blue'], 
  linewidth=2, label='Price')

  plot_vol = axes[1]
  plot_vol.bar(date, vol, width=15, color='darkgrey')
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? Maybe the dataframe is not sorted by date

Comment: Probably your time data is not sorted. You can try to sort it in ascending order.

Comment: Thank you Zephyr and Hakan Akgün for your answer. It works!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort Pandas Dataframe by Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161356/sort-pandas-dataframe-by-date)

Comment: You are welcome @Danial Wozniak :)