# Python: Order Dates that are in the format: %B %Y

Tags: python, date, sorting, datetime

I have a df with dates in the format %B %Y (e.g. June 2021, December 2022 etc.)

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| Apr 2022 | 2 |
| Dec 2021 | 8 |

I am trying to sort dates in order of oldest to newest but when I try:

```
.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
```

it is ordering in alphabetical order.

The 'Date' column is an Object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Column to Date Format (Pandas Dataframe)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161356/convert-column-to-date-format-pandas-dataframe) Your problem is the same as in this linked question - you need to convert your column from object to date or datetime.

Comment: `ascending=False` will result in sorting newest to oldest, not oldest to newest

Comment: Try `df.sort_values('Date', key=pd.to_datetime)`

Comment: @Stef feel free to add an answer, ill upvote :)

Comment: Oh, it looks like someone had posted an answer, but then deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

- `ascending=False` will sort from newest to oldest, but you are asking to sort oldest to newest, so you don't need that option;
- there is a `key` option to specify how to parse the values before sorting them;
- you may or may not want option `ignore_index=True`, which I included below.

We can use the `key` option to parse the values into `datetime` objects with `pandas.to_datetime`.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['Apr 2022', 'Dec 2021', 'May 2022', 'May 2021'], 'Price': [2, 8, 12, 15]})

df = df.sort_values(by='Date', ignore_index=True, key=pd.to_datetime)

print(df)
#        Date  Price
# 0  May 2021     15
# 1  Dec 2021      8
# 2  Apr 2022      2
# 3  May 2022     12
```

Relevant documentation:

- [DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html);
- [to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html).